# Use controllers from git submodule in Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git-submodules

does anyone know if it's possible to use controllers of a submodule in a Rails application? My submodule currently has a few models which work perfectly but I'd need to add one or two controllers which are also shared between two applications.

Any help or suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to extract the useful model/methods, put them into a plugin or gem, either privately or publicly.

Then you can use the plugin/gem in multiple applications, and have the chance to improve the gem over time, benefiting all of your applications.

Comment: Yeah, figured out that'd be the best solution. Thanks!